# What is the name of the set defined by nonnegative linear combinations of a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In $\bf R^d$ I have $n$ vectors $\vec x_1, ...,  \vec x_n$. The object in question is the set of points (with origin $\vec 0$) that can be formed as a linear combination of these vectors *with only nonnegative coefficients*.

What is the name of this shape? (I have a different question on how it can be determine, without solving obvious matrix equations, if a point $\vec v$ is inside or outside (or on the hull) of this shape, and I hope I can find something on the net about it once I know the proper name for this thing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those special linear combinations are called [conical combinations,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination) and the resulting  set is called the conical hull of those vectors. The conical hull is always a convex cone.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the name for it is the *convex cone* of these vectors.  In general a convex cone is any set of elements $v,u$ where $av+bu$ belongs to the set again as long as $a,b\geq0$.

Comment: Sounds good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

Comment: The set in question is *a* convex cone, but there is no such thing as "*the* convex cone *of* a set of vectors". Rather, it is called the *conical hull* of the vectors, as celtschk's answer states. The situation is similar to the difference between a subspace and the span of a set of vectors. @Gyro